# Large table of pairwise friction values?

Tags: friction, resource-recommendations, material-science, data

Small table of pairwise friction coefficients (i.e., "rubber vs concrete", "leather vs oak") exist online:

- https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html
- https://www.engineersedge.com/coeffients_of_friction.htm

These are on the order of 50-60 unique material types and 100-200 of pairwise combinations.

My primary question is where could I find significantly larger tables of pairwise coefficients?

A subquestion is what are the original sources/references for these tables found online? Are they somehow common knowledge or are these based off of original experiments with an associated text/article describing their measurement?

> I realize that friction is a complicated phenomenon which is very poorly approximated by these simple pairwise coefficients. If the complexity of friction is why larger tables don't exist, it'd still be useful for me to understand the lineage of these pairwise tables that are commonly found online.

Comment: Seems that the table floating around comes from Dudley Fuller's section "2d. Coefficients of Friction" in the _American Institute of Physics Handbook_. https://archive.org/details/ost-physics-americaninstituteofphysicshandbook/page/n53/mode/2up

Answer (score 0):

If you have 50 different materials, then including friction coefficients with self, then you should have $50^2=2500$ entries. The rate of growth of these tables make it ridiculous to expect a full listing.

Also, once you consider the self-friction, you are immediately in trouble. Feynman lectures talk about how, if you polish two pieces of highly purified metals of the same composition, say, the union of the two metals in vacuum often leads to welding, because the atoms of the two metals will cease to know the difference between them. i.e. friction is a surface dirt dependent quantity, and all such tables are thus approximations. You are better off measuring as you need them.